# Is there a way to filter and print a particular pattern without repeating code?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

If I use `pacman` to install software, I occasionally run into errors of the form

```
package-name: /some/package/file exists in filesystem
```

This usually occurs if I've messed up an installation at some time in the past, unwisely tried to install something manually and so on.

In order to deal with the problem, it's useful to have the names of all the conflicting packages together in one file.  I can do this using

```
# pacman -S package-name |
   grep '^package-name: [^ ]* exists in filesystem$' |
   sed 's/^package-name: \([^ ]*\) exists in filesystem$/\1/' >
   conflicting_files.txt
```

However, this requires me to type the same thing twice.  Is there a way to do the same thing without duplicating the regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many ways. For instance, using `sed` alone (I am assumong GNU tools here since you're using `pacman`):

```
pacman -S package-name |
   sed -En 's/^package-name: ([^ ]*) exists in filesystem$/\1/p' >
   conflicting_files.txt
```

Or `grep`:

```
pacman -S package-name |
   grep -oP '^package-name: \K\S+' >
   conflicting_files.txt
```

If you need to match the end of the line, use @RomanPerekhrest's [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394788/22222).

Or `perl`:

```
pacman -S package-name |
   perl -ne 's/^package-name: (\S*) exists in filesystem$/$1/ && print' >
   conflicting_files.txt
```

Or `perl`:

```
pacman -S package-name |
    perl -lane 'print $F[1] if /^package-name:.*exists in filesystem$/' >
    conflicting_files.txt
```

Or `awk`:

```
pacman -S package-name |
    awk '/^package-name:.*exists in filesystem$/{print $2}' > 
    conflicting_files.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep` you may shorten your pipeline to the following:

```
pacman -S package-name | grep -Po '^package-name: \K[^[:space:]]+(?= exists in filesystem$)' > conflicting_files.txt
```

Alternatively, you can also change `[^[:space:]]` to `\S` to match ***non-whitespace*** sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing in yet another option:

```
packman -S package-name |
  pcregrep -xo1 'package-name: (\S+) exists in filesystem'
```

Similar to:

```
packman -S package-name |
  perl -lne 'print $1 if /^package-name: (\S+) exists in filesystem$/'
```

The portable/POSIX way would be:

```
sed -n 's/^package-name: \([^ ]*\) exists in filesystem$/\1/p'
```